# how to check already executed programs in Linux?

Tags: scripts, cron, process, ps

I'm running various *Cron* tasks in my *Linux* machine. Recently I updated it and want to check if it is working fine. For example:

```
0 6 * * 1-5 /scripts/foo.sh
```

Except for the case that I check during the scheduled time that the process is actually running `ps x` , is there a way to simply check the executed program/scripts within last 24 hours or something like that?

I'm new to Linux. Any idea/hint will work for me!

Comment: Not that I can think of.  But you can make it write a log file.  And then output `date` at the beginning and `date` at the end.  But, without you doing more, it doesn't keep track of what programs have run, regardless of whether or not you used `cron`.  That's something you'll need to do yourself.  Some sysadmin programs that you can set up to run with `cron` (i.e., backup programs) would write to `/var/log`, for example.

Comment: Are you running a flavor of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add date and printf statements near the beginning and end of my scripts to write the date and time to a text file in my home directory. I also direct the output to that file so it records the output you would get if it was run in a terminal. Here is an example

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

date >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt

printf "pizero Starting!\n" >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt

rsync -avh pi@pizero1.local:/home/pi/Python /home/john/pizero1 >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt 2>&1

printf "pizero Done!\n\n" >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt

date >> /home/john/anacronjobs.txt

exit
```

Using the >> operator ensures it appends to rather than overwrites the file

The output looks like this

```
Sun 14 Feb 11:06:04 GMT 2021
pizero Starting!
receiving incremental file list
Python/test.txt

sent 6.53K bytes  received 6.42K bytes  278.52 bytes/sec
total size is 1.17M  speedup is 90.55
pizero Done!
```

Comment: Easier to add timestamp using `ts`, `printf "some string" | ts >> file`

Answer (score 1):

Cron traditionally logs to `/var/log/syslog`, so a simple `grep` for the strings `CRON` and/or `foo.sh` should determine whether execution was attempted.

On modern `systemd`-based systems, you can access equivalent log entries via `journalctl` ex.

```
journalctl -u cron.service --since -1day | grep -F foo.sh
```

or perhaps

```
journalctl -u cron.service --grep 'foo\.sh' --since -1day
```

if your system's `journalctl` was compiled with pattern matching support.