# Script runs without echoing

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a simple shell script that includes the following lines

```
echo "Hello"

g++ main.cpp -o mainOutput

echo "Shell script ended!"
```

When I run the script using a terminal, it echoes the messages properly.
It doesn't act the same if I run it by double-clicking on it.
It just creates the `mainOutput` without any messages.

I want my script to act the same in both situations. What do you think that I am doing wrong?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/20353/945853

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The accepted answer suggests appending `$SHELL`  at the end of the script. But, it didn't change anything

Comment: If you double-click on it to run it, that doesn't start a terminal usually, so there's nowhere to show the echoed messages. But the `echo` commands do run.

Comment: @muru So you say that running a shell script by double-clicking on it is not the proper way.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You could, for example, detect if the script is running in a terminal (e.g., `if [[ -t 0 ]] ...`) and then use `echo` or use `zenity` to show messages otherwise.

Comment: I answered a related question yesterday https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316538/how-to-check-already-executed-programs-in-linux/1316591#1316591 You might find this approach helpful